# Box2D Polygon Bodies not rotating

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to create a game with "libGDX" and "Box2D".
I've several shapes in the game, so I created a `BodyFactory` class which creates my bodies using `PolygonShape`

The problem is, when I create a body, with `Shape.setAsBox()` method, everything works fine, but when I create bodies with `PolygonShape.set(vertices)`, the position of bodies changes as I wish, but they won't rotate at all.

This is what I get (after stability) when I drop 3 bodies from the sky:

[image]
The square rotates and stays at the ground, bot the other shapes won't.

Also note that I tried adding

```
body.setFixedRotation(false);
```

to my code, but nothing changed.

Also friction, mass and density of shapes are at a reasonable amount.

This is the part of my code which creates a "PolygonShape" from a file:

```
...
Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
...
for (int i = 0; i < bodyConf.meshData.length; i++) {
    PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();
    polygonShape.set(bodyConf.meshData[i]);
    fixtureDef.shape = polygonShape;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    polygonShape.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are creating only *one* `Body` with *three* `Fixture`s attached to it.

What you actually want is *three* `Body`s, with *one* `Fixture` attached to each of them. That way, each body can rotate independent from the others.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bodyConf.meshData.length; i++) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = ...;
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();
    polygonShape.set(bodyConf.meshData[i]);
    fixtureDef.shape = polygonShape;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    polygonShape.dispose();
}
```

Comment: please help me on this , I'm trying to implement your inventory dnd code in my game but when I test the InventoryScreen I just see a green screen without the Inventory window I've just made this change in your code : TextureAtlas icons = new TextureAtlas("icons/icons.atlas"); instead of : TextureAtlas icons = LibgdxUtils.assets.get("icons/icons.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the right place to discuss this. Open a new question if you want help, or maybe visit #libgdx on freenode IRC. People there can help you as well.